# MVC design Pattern - Designing a Model

Tags: ios, design-patterns, model-view-controller, model

I've been working with mvc design pattern to develop iOS, and I was wondering if I'm doing this right. I've read a lot about MVC, and, in my concept, all information that will be displayed or will change view's characteristics will be stored at the model (as it is the 'knowledge' of my vc). So, in my way designing MVCs, I usually create a mvc to each view that users interact, and I have model objects that manages all 'shared' information across the App, and one singleton to persist some data, the 'UserSession' class. For example:

In my HomeViewController I have different subviews depending the status of my objects, so in this MVC (home) I have a 'presenter' as a model that controls my homeSubview type and their data. When I need to retrieve information from another model object (like user, or whatever object) is my 'presenter model' who do the trick (in this case), and the same happens in another mvc inside the project. My ways is something like:

Controller [ask to] Model (that communicate with others model if needed) which ['respond' to] Controller then [update the] View

So, that looks good to me, but I fell like I'm not using the mvc pattern correctly.  Can someone give a opinion?

In advance: sorry about the english. And I appreciate any suggestion/help, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with what you are suggesting, though it sounds more like a MVVM(C) pattern rather than MVC.

So in iOS we are pretty much forced to use view controllers, so we need the extra (C) here, but essentially:

- M (model), these should represent your data model.

  `class Model {
      var firstName: String
      var lastName: String
      ....
  }`
- V (view), this should handle presentation, drawing to the screen, and displaying data

  `class View: UIView {
      let fullNameLabel = UILabel()
  }`
- VM (view model), this is where you adapt the data in your model to fit what your view needs. This is good because if you have multiple views that display data from the same model class you need only add a new view model, to adapt the data that it wants, rather than clutter up your model with lots of helper methods

  `class ViewModel {
      let model: Model
      func fullName() -> String {
          return "(model.firstName) (model.lastName)"
      }
  }`

And obviously we also have out controller that orchestrates the whole thing :)

It feels to me like this is more what you are doing, where your `presenter` is the view model.

This helps to encapsulate the functionality that doesn't really belong in either your view or model. The full name is not technically part of the data model, nor todo with rendering/presentation, so we move it to a adapter/presenter/view model (whatever you want to call it).

Maybe this is of some help to you? Feel free to include code examples for any other info if you want anymore feedback/have any more questions ‍

Comment: Thank you again! Actually I'm getting more to Viper design. And I only meet viper later.. https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/viper/ 
But I'm steel trying to maintain mvc..